# C++ WINAPI TreeView - tooltips for items

Tags: c++, windows, treeview

I've seen it couple of times in other programs, so its definitely possible.

I have some ideas, but not very good ones. 
Using TreeView_HitTest detect hovering item and manually display tooltip or somehow through WM_NOTIFY ...

Comment: The tree supports label unfolding via tooltips, but if you want different text displayed I think you'd have to implement it yourself as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's quite simple, should read documentation better.

Just set TVS_INFOTIP style and handle TVN_GETINFOTIP message.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270410(v=vs.85).aspx